# How to Transfer slo-mo video from one mac to other in photos.app with slow motion edits options?

Tags: macos, iphone, video, photos.app

I have a slo-mo video imported from iPhone to my photos app. Now I need to transfer this from photos of my mac to other mac's photo.

I tried by exporting my video as a file in finder and later imported back to the photos app. The slow motion video is working as expected at right timings, but the editing mode is lost. i.e: We cannot alter the timing or frame of the slow motion thereafter.

What can be done if it need to import the video again with the slo-mo frame edit options available.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. *In Finder:*

   - Create a folder for the media you want to transfer.
2. *In the Photos app:*

   1. Select the media that you want to transfer.
   2. In the menu bar, select `File > Export > Export Unmodified Original For...`
   3. Select `Export`
   4. Choose folder from step one
3. Transfer the folder from step one to the Mac where you want to import the photos
4. *In the Photos app on that Mac:*

   1. In the menu bar, select `File > Import...`
   2. Select the folder you exported from step one
   3. Select `Review for Import`
   4. Follow the dialog.
5. Enjoy.

(But do note: If you made a modification to the slow motion segment, it will be reset to the default after export. I'd love for this to be amended, but I suppose we're beholden to Apple for that...)

Comment: This still seems to be the only way to preserve the editing mode of Slo-mo videos. Using airdrop to share Slo-mo videos removes the editing mode.